# Как программно создать кастомный CheckBox

Tags: android, checkbox, xamarin

Есть такой xml:

```
<CheckBox   android:id="@+id/cbAllBrands"   
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    android:text="@string/AllBrands"   
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"   
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"    
    android:theme="@style/GreenTheme" />
```

Работает прекрасно. Но необходимо создать программно такой же CheckBox, не получается подтянуть тему. Какие решения, господа ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете создать леяут-файл с единственным элементом в разметке - необходимым чекбоксом, и инфлейтить его во `View` при помощи `LayoutInflater`. В XML вы можете указать тему.

Comment: Спасибо. Получилось!